# How to show progress indicator when loading objects for widget configuration intent?

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit

In my application, a user can show widget configuration and change some options by selecting them from a dynamic list that is handled by Intents Extension, but first it must be downloaded from the backend.

Fetch may take some time and until it is finished nothing happens, the user still sees the configuration panel. Therefore, I would like to show some progress indicator, but I'm not sure if it is possible.

The automatically generated protocol `MyIntentHandling` from `.intentdefinition` file provides only two possible methods to handle this case: `provideMyOptionsCollection` and `handle`.

However, the first one doesn't provide completion to indicate progress and the second one is never called. Below those methods:

```swift
extension IntentHandler: MyIntentHandling {
    func provideMyOptionsCollection(for intent: MyConfigurationIntent, searchTerm: String?, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<IntentData>?, Error?) -> Void) {
        // fetch...
        completion(INObjectCollection(sections: fetchedData))
    }

    func handle(intent: MyConfigurationIntent, completion: @escaping (MyConfigurationIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        return .init(code: .inProgress, userActivity: nil)
    }
}
```

I think that `provideMyOptionsCollection` should automatically show progress, because this methods is meant for asynchronous operations. Therefore, it is quite strange that the system instead of showing progress indicator, it does nothing.

Here is an example of the feature that I'm implementing:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I also have this problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: @Jonge, nope. I don’t think there is any solution.